# Manage torrent from command line and download files sequentially

Tags: linux, bittorrent, rtorrent

I need a way to manage torrent without any sort of GUI and download the pieces on sequential order. Does anybody knows how to do it?

rtorrent is text based but, as far as I know, don't download files sequentially.

qbittorrent-nox have the feature of downloading it sequentially but I have to use the browser to control the torrent.

Comment: You should certainly be able to download individual files with rtorrent, in whatever order you like. From the files list, you can turn off downloading of each file by pressing the spacebar, then enable them in order. It won't happen automatically, though (although it might be possible to script that).

Comment: I might have expressed myself wrong. The file itself should be downloaded in sequential order. If it's a video, I should be able to start playing it before the download ends.

Comment: @DiogoMelo That's kind of completely against both the benefits of and spirit of torrents in the first place... it may work out great for you but it's not going to help the swarm much. Why do you want to start playing the video before the download ends? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: @JasonC, users' time is precious. The fastest the file can be played, the better. I understand in some situations it goes again't the common good, but 1) I intend to keep the ratio greater than 1 and 2) in 99% of the cases the torrents I will handle won't have number of seeders much inferior to the number of peers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good wikipedia article with [comparisons of torrent client features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients).

From there, clients that support sequential downloads:

- qBittorrent
- KTorrent
- Vuze
- BitComet
- uTorrent
- Xunlei
- Shareaza ("available in mod client")

Of those, clients that run on Linux:

- qBittorrent
- KTorrent
- Vuze

Of those, clients with command line support:

- KTorrent ("partial")
- Vuze ("partial")

I'm not sure what "partial" means but that list narrows down your options to either KTorrent or Vuze. You'll have to check their command line interface documentation to see if they support the features you need. You may have to e.g. set sequential options via the GUI once if the CLI does not support that as an option (if you find where they store their preferences perhaps you could automate this at install) - but who knows, check the CLI first, it might do everything you need.

All three of qBittorrent, KTorrent, and Vuze support a web interface of some sort as well, so even if they don't have native command line support for what you need, if you can do it through the web then you may be able to write scripts / programs to automate the tasks. In particular qBittorrent and KTorrent both say they have "remote control through web", so if native command line support does fail, those may be the two to look into first as far as automation scripts go. Vuze supports that as well, although you need to install the appropriate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Peerflix](https://github.com/mafintosh/peerflix) supports this.

```
trr () {
(
    peerflix "$@" --path "${PEERFLIX_DIR:-$HOME/Downloads/Video}" --mpv -- --fullscreen
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found was utilizing a private RSS stream and programmatically posting the torrents to it.  You can then hook your qBittorent client into the RSS stream and it will essentially download anything you publish.

Would be great if they created a REST service endpoint or command line alternative.

Answer (score -1):

I know your pain.  Qbittorrent is by far the best with sequential downloading but the web based gui doesn't support it.  It ultimately is just a problem with the gui.  I'm going to suggest the hard way.  In fact it may appear difficult enough that some might think the suggestion is sarcastic.  It just might be easy though and depending on how badly you need this sequentially downloading seedbox it may just be worth looking into.

The way to get this to work is to fork the code at github, found here https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent, and add that gui element and bind it to what it needs to be bound to.  Could be hard, could be easy.  It all depends on your background and how it was coded.

If you do go that route be sure to merge-request when you are done so the rest of us can have it. ;)

Comment: QBittorrent Web UI has been supporting sequential download for quite a while now.